# Microservice crashed after few mins of deployment with message 'failure to get a peer from the ring-balancer'

Tags: microservices

I have a microservice, implemented on C# (.NET). Upon deployment of this service on Azure Kubernetes, the service runs for a few minutes and then suddenly crashes/fails with the following error

'failure to get a peer from the ring-balancer'

Any help, how this error can be resolved?

My SRE team is saying that error lies with the microservice, while my development team is saying that error lies with infrastructure (SRE) team.